# Quadratic factor to complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, quadratics

How to convert this quadratic factor to complex number form? (With steps please)
Reference: $Z = a + bi$, $i = \sqrt{-1}$

$$-3 + \frac{\sqrt{-12}}{2}$$

Thanks!

Comment: @Mathmo123  didn't know how to begin since I could factor out sqrt(-1) from sqrt(-1) from sqrt(-12)/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$-3+\frac{\sqrt{-12}}{2} = -3 + \frac{\sqrt{12}\cdot\sqrt{-1}}{2}$$

Comment: = -3 + sqrt(3)i. Thanks.